# How to set system cache memory on windows 10

Tags: mongodb, caching, memory-management

When running Mongod I get the following WARNING: The file system cache of this machine is configured to be greater than 40% of the total memory. This can lead to increased memory pressure and poor performance.  This is on a windows 10 pro 64 bit machine.

Comment: I think you get better answers on [dba.se].

Comment: thanks, I'll try that

Comment: Also, there's a DocHub link for information relating to this issue: http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/wt-windows-system-file-cache - I believe it should actually point here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/production-notes/#id3